# MUI datagrid specific rows with bold text

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I have a simple mui datagrid in my react project where I get data via an api. It'll loop through the data and create a variable amount of cols and rows. The data specifies per row if the data in that row should be bold or not.

Now how do I make it such that the text in a row (where style='bold' according to api data) is indeed bold?

I've wasted a lot of time trying to achieve this but I can't seem to figure it out with the documentation alone (I'm new to React)

Comment: Does the API return a valid HTML element? Do you have an example of what it returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use renderCell method to achieve this

```
renderCell: (params) => {
      if (style=='bold') // You need to add the condition of your loop here
              return (<strong>{params.row}</strong>);
```